# Reading AWS environment variables using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I've configured AWS CLI in my laptop.  I'm passing the region details etc either at prompt or baked as part of the code. I'm able to connect to aws through python and read the items.
But when trying to develop a class so that it get the environment variables like AWS_REGION, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY etc all that is returned is null.  Is there anything i'm missing apart from configuring the aws cli in my laptop.  **Take note while installing it in my (windows) laptop, at the prompt i enter the AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY etc.**

Thanks

Comment: Rather than storing this information in Environment Variables, it is better to store it in a configuration file. An easy way to create the configuration file is to run `aws configure`. This will store information in `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials`. Environment Variables are typically used to _override_ such configurations, or if it is not possible to create the configuration files. Your code never needs to access the configuration information -- the AWS SDK (eg boto3 for Python) will automatically retrieve the information. There is no need to retrieve/access such information.

Answer (score 2):

So when you downloaded the AWS CLI the first time it sounds like you went through `aws configure` which asked for your credentials. [AWS CLI config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)

So when you run AWS commands (CLI or Boto3) one of the first places it will look for credentials is this config file `%AWS_CONFIG_FILE%`. So it knows what your default region is by reading this config file.

What are you exactly trying to build? For reading environment variables, this sounds like a LAMBDA function which would have the environment variables set for `AWS_REGION` etc. If still testing on your local machine, you will have to set those yourself prior to testing in the environment variables.

Comment: a one time data load is required to be done to a DB.  Idea is to achieve this via a python script.  DB credentials are stored in secrets manager. When ran the boto3 library need to read the region information and access the mentioned secret in code.  This is to avoid facing password rotation issue and sharing passwords with the deployment team.

Comment: @luckyluke if this is meant to be a dev script to run on your local machine then you should just set the `AWS_REGION` yourself.

```python
import os

os.environ['AWS_REGION'] = 'us-east-2'
```